# Minimizing functionals constrained in a box

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I would like to draw a curve between two points that minimizes the square of the second derivative integrated along the curve.

$J(y) = \int_{1}^{0} {y}''^2 dx $

The first derivative for the start and end point are known and must be preserved, and all values on the curve between the start and end point must fall within some range l < e < u.

$y(0) = a, y(1) = b, y'(0) = c, y'(1) = d$

$y(t) = e, \forall t \in [0, 1] \implies l < e < u$

Additionally the curve should be continuous in the interval.

Sincere thanks to Wadim Zudilin for recommending posting an example, I know realize my first post was not even asking the right thing :(

Comment: In this vague formulation (without any example!), it's hard to be helpful. The only related optimization problem is Lagrange multipliers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multipliers) and its variational generalization, Pontryagin's principle.

Comment: Perhaps you can set the potential energy to infinity outside the box, like they do in billiards. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards

Comment: @Wadim - Yes it is vague. This is very much outside my area of expertise and I don't really know the correct terminology to express the problem, for that I apologize. 

@muad - Thank you for the suggestion. Glancing at the formulation of dynamically billiards it looks like a promising route, although admittedly I am unsure of how to translate a problem expressed in terms of energy to a problem where the conditions are expressed in velocity and position.




Comment: A bit confused: the box is one dimensional? (Since you write l < y(t) < u) Then can't you use the fundamental theorem and conclude that for any path, J(y) = c - d? Or do you actually want to minimize |y''| instead? 

Comment: Yes. Or $y''^2$. I'll update.

Comment: @muad: billiard is probably not the right potential to use, at least by itself. If the solution bounces off the walls then the second derivative of y cannot be square integrable (as it'd contain a delta function). So you probably need condition that whenever $y(t) = l \implies y'(t) = 0, y''(t) \geq 0$ and similarly for the upper bound. 

Comment: I think the unconstrained general problem is solved by polynomial $y(t) = k_3 t^3 + k_2 t^2 + k_1 t + k_0$. For the constrained problem, the answer is probably a piecewise cubic polynomial defined on intervals $[0,\tau_1],[\tau_1,\tau_2],[\tau_2,1]$ such that $y(0) = a$, $y(1) = b$, $y'(0) = c$, $y'(1) = d$, $l \leq y(\tau_1), y(\tau_2) \leq u$, $y'(\tau_1) = y'(\tau_2) = 0$ and $|y''(\tau_1^-)| = |y''(\tau_^1+)|$, ditto for the second derivative at $\tau_2$. (There may, of course, be only 1 break point, or none, but no more than two.) Though the above is physical intuition, not mathematics.

Comment: Eck, made a typo. The non-parsed expression for second derivatives at $\tau_1$ is $|y''(\tau_1^-)| = |y''(\tau_1^+)|$, that the left and right limits of the derivatives are equal in absolute value. 

Comment: Independently, I showed (or rather, convinced myself via very non-rigorous application of Lagrange multipliers) that $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} y''$ is composed of delta functions centered at the break points where $y = l$ or $y = u$. So I think you're right, and you don't need the absolute values around $y''(\tau_1^-) = y''(\tau_1^+)$.

Comment: @Rahul: you are absolutely right. y''' needs to be locally integrable. Also, on second thought, there can be allowed arbitrary number of break points. I don't think it is reasonable to limit it to just two. 

Comment: @Willie and @muad. I will add an additional constraint that I want the curve to be continuous. Thanks Willie.

Comment: @Willie Let me see if can pull out an algorithm from your suggestion. First solve the unconstrained problem. If the resultant curve crosses the boundary, break it into two problems using the point of intersection. Repeat the process until there are no crossings. Is that close?

Comment: No, you cannot use the point of intersection. (I am again waffling on the maximum number of breakpoints.) If the unconstrained problem remains bounded in the interval, you are done. If not, you need to iterate on the number of break points. Observe that for each "segment", by prescribing $y(\tau_1), y(\tau_2), y'(\tau_1), y'(\tau_2)$ (unless $\tau_1$ or $\tau_2$ are 0 or 1, the function takes values either $l$ or $u$ with derivatives 0) you generate coefficients for a cubic polynomial depending on the prescribed values. Then you try to impose the continuity of the second derivative. 

Comment: This is done by varying the times of the break points (the coefficients depends on the prescribed break points, as the values taken at the break points are fixed). If this cannot be done, then add more break points. I am inclined to believe now that two break points suffice always. But one has to compute to find out. The third derivative will, in general, not be continuous. 

Comment: I'm still unsure how I decide where to place the breakpoints. Are there unique spots, or do you use heuristics?

Comment: You solve for the break points by requiring the second derivative to be continuous. If you fix a set of break points then in each sub-interval those break points uniquely determine the boundary conditions for the cubic polynomial (by giving the value at those points and its first derivative). Thus the left limit of the second derivative at $\tau_1$ is a function of $\tau_1$, the right limit is a function of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ etc. By setting the right limits equal to the left limits, you should have the same number of equations as breakpoints. Try to solve the system. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to elaborate a bit on what Rahul and I mentioned in the comments.

Take the action functional to be $\int_0^1 (y'')^2 dt$, with prescribed boundary conditions $y(0) = a$, $y(1) = b$, $y'(0) = c$, $y'(1) = d$. For finding the free evolution, take the variation of the function relative to $y$ and set it to zero. Immediately this gives
$$\int_0^1 y'' (\delta y)'' dt = 0 $$
for any perturbation. The boundary conditions prescribed implies that $\delta y(0) = \delta y(1) = \delta y'(0) = \delta y'(1) = 0$. So we are allowed to integrate by parts twice (assuming the solution is $C^4$) and obtain $y'''' = 0$, which implies that $y(t)$ is a cubic polynomial in time and thus has 4 free parameters, which we can fix by the boundary values.

The intuition for the bounded case is that, until the evolution hits the wall, locally the equation of motion should be identical to the free evolution. So the solution should be composed piecewise of cubic polynomials. Every time it hits the wall it should receive a hard impact, which suggests that $y''''(\tau_i) = c\delta_{\tau_i}$, the Dirac delta. (The same way that for a hard billiard which away from the walls travel via $x'' = 0$ receive a delta function impact in the second derivative when it hits a wall.) This suggests that $y'''$ is a step function of $t$, and $y''$ is continuous.

For an example, let $l = -1, u = 1$, let the initial time be $t = 0$, and final time be $t = 2$. Let $a = b = 0$, and $c = d = 6$.

First solve the free problem: we want 
$$ k_3 t^3 + k_2 t^2 + k_1 t + k_0 = y(t) $$
Plugging in the values for the four points we find by solving the linear system that the equation should be
$$ y(t) = 3t^3 - 9 t^2 + 6t $$
which achieves its local max and min in $[0,2]$ at $1\pm \sqrt{1/3}$, at which points $|y| = |\pm \sqrt{4/3}| > 1$. So the free evolution is no go.

There should be two break points, but for illustration we try first with one break point. Assume the break point is at $\tau$ where $y(\tau) = 1$. So we have a system of equations using the data at the points $2,0,\tau$ and the cubic ansatz
$$ y |_{[0,\tau]} = \sum \alpha_kt^k,\qquad y|_{[\tau,2]} = \sum \beta_k t^k$$ 
which leads to 
$$\alpha_0 = 0, \alpha_1 = 6, \alpha_3 \tau^3 + \alpha_2\tau^2 + 6 \tau = 1, 3\alpha_3\tau^2 + 2\alpha_2\tau + 6 = 0$$
and
$$8\beta_3 + 4\beta_2 + 2\beta_1 + \beta_0 = 0, 12\beta_3 + 4\beta_2 + \beta_1 = 6, \beta_3\tau^3 + \beta_2\tau^2 + \beta_1\tau + \beta_0 = 1, 3\beta_3\tau^2 + 2\beta_2\tau + \beta_1 = 0$$
which gives
$$\alpha_0 = 0, \alpha_1 = 6, \alpha_2 = -12 / \tau, \alpha_3 = 6 / \tau^2$$
$$\beta_3 = (6\tau - 2)/(\tau - 2)^3, \beta_2 = -3(5\tau^2 - 3\tau + 6) / 2(\tau - 2)^3 $$
Continuity of $y''$ then implies 
$$ 6\tau \alpha_3 + 2\alpha_2 = 6 \tau\beta_3 + 2\beta_2 $$
or
$$ 3\tau^2 + 23 \tau^2 - 42 \tau - 32 = 0$$
which has two negative roots and one positive one at $\tau = 2$ which we can throw out. And thus 1 break point it not enough.

A direct computation (if I did it right, which is not guaranteed) with 2 break points $\sigma\in [1,2]$ and $\tau \in[0,1]$ yields that $\tau = 1/2$ and $\sigma = 3/2$ an admissible pair. It is just linear algebra in the end.

Comment: This is very cool. I'm still go over your work, but the process makes sense to me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hum, the last paragraph is almost surely wrong. I shouldn't do computation that late at night. 

Comment: Solving the equation, you should have that $\sigma$ is the real root of $4\sigma^3 + \sigma^2 - 4\sigma - 10$, which Wolfram Alpha tells me is $\left( -1 + \sqrt[3]{2087 + 36\sqrt{3270}} + \sqrt[3]{2087 - 36\sqrt{3270}}\right) / 12$ which is roughly 1.51